# pandas json_normalize single/double quotes

Tags: javascript, json, pandas, json-normalize

I have a structure as follows:-

```json
{
  "data" : {
      "links" :[{"url" : "https://foo", "title" : "St. Mary's Church"}]
  }
}
```

I am using pandas to output this to Excel format, edit and then import.

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter(parameters['path']) as writer:
    df = pd.json_normalize(features)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="test)
```

The problem is that pandas is writing this field out as follows into the Excel column data.links:-

```
[{'url' : 'https://foo', 'title' : "St. Mary's Church"}]
```

I want to read it back in as JSON using javascript but JSON.parse fails as the object keys have single quotes. I cannot globally convert to double quotes (easily) as that causes issues with the apostrophe in St. Mary's.

Is there a better solution in pandas? Or a straightforward regex to convert the string back to JSON in javascript. I can only use native javascript, do not have access to third party libraries.

Comment: Why don't you export directly to json using `df.to_json('output.json')`?

Comment: User needs to edit Excel sheet

Comment: Hi, why not reimporting the Excel file modified by user with Pandas and then export to json, again with Pandas?

Comment: The complication is that we use pandas to write to XLSX and ogr2ogr to read back in. A javascript process is passed the column's data as a text field. The reason we use ogr2ogr is that we fire multiple different formats at it (xlsx, geopackage, geojson etc...) which pandas won't handle automatically.